# Iterative Function Nesting with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Currently, I am trying to provide a more dynamic interface for a set of controls using PHP to interface with a MySQL database and to form a json string that gets sent to a client-side script.

Everything about it works except that I can't seem to nest a function call within itself. My suspicions are telling me maybe its an issue with variable scope, but I don't know how to go about testing if that's even the cause.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "Categories": {
    "2": {
      "Name": "Store Name",
      "Parent": "0",
      "Prefix": "SN",
      "Published": "1"
    },
    "5": {
      "Name": "Apparel",
      "Parent": "2",
      "Prefix": "A",
      "Published": "1"
    },
    "27": {
      "Name": "Hats",
      "Parent": "5",
      "Prefix": "H",
      "Published": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
(function(){

  function jint_categories(parentId, categoryData) {
    var jObjUL = $('<ul />');
    $.each(categoryData.Categories, function(key_i, val_i) {
      if(parseInt(val_i.Parent) == parseInt(parentId)) {
        var jObjLI = $('<li class="category" />').appendTo(jObjUL);
        var jObjDiv = $('<div class="controls" />').appendTo(jObjLI);
        $('<a href="#" class="view">&nbsp;</a>').appendTo(jObjDiv);
        $('<a href="" class="edit">'+val_i.Name+'</a>').appendTo(jObjDiv);
        jint_categories(val_i.Parent, categoryData).appendTo(jObjLI);
      }
    });
    return jObjUL;
  }

  var jJsonData, jJsonDiv;

  $(document).on('ready', function() {

    // Prepare Interface Container
    jJsonDiv = $('#jint-categories');
    jJsonData = $.parseJSON(jJsonDiv.html());
    jJsonDiv.empty();

    // Populate Interface Container
    $(jint_categories(0, jJsonData)).appendTo(jJsonDiv);

  }

})();
```

When I comment out the self-reference inside the function, the top level of my category tree is returned as expected. The only error message I get in Chrome Console is "error" and the stack the operation took (useless here because only 1 thing is being done by this script).

Again, my suspicions are currently centering around variable scope within the function, which may or may not be the cause. Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recursing infinitely because you're passing the wrong `parentId` value when you make the recursive call. It should be `key_i`, not `val_i.Parent`, since the latter is the same as the `parentId` from this call.

```
function jint_categories(parentId, categoryData) {
    var jObjUL = $('<ul />');
    $.each(categoryData.Categories, function (key_i, val_i) {
        if (parseInt(val_i.Parent) == parseInt(parentId)) {
            var jObjLI = $('<li class="category" />').appendTo(jObjUL);
            var jObjDiv = $('<div class="controls" />').appendTo(jObjLI);
            $('<a href="#" class="view">&nbsp;</a>').appendTo(jObjDiv);
            $('<a href="" class="edit">' + val_i.Name + '</a>').appendTo(jObjDiv);
            jint_categories(key_i, categoryData).appendTo(jObjLI);
        }
    });
    return jObjUL;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/C4u3m/3/)

Comment: Oh my god. You're right. Thank you so much. It's been a long trek lol!